# Why the description of the snmp oid giving "null"?

Tags: c, linux, net-snmp, mib

My following code is not working as I want to get the description of a node using the Net-Snmp library.

```
#include "net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h"
#include "net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h"

void  print_s(struct tree *);

    int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
        char buff[100]; 
        struct tree *node=NULL;

        init_mib();
        node=read_all_mibs();
        if( node == NULL )
        {
        exit(2);
        }
        print_s(node);  
    } 


void  print_s(struct tree *tree)
    {       
    struct tree    *tp; 

    for (tp = tree->child_list; tp; tp = tp->next_peer) 
    {
printf("%s:%s\n",tp->label,tp->description); 
    }
    for (tp = tree->child_list; tp; tp = tp->next_peer) 
          {           
              if (tp->child_list)
                  print_s(tp);
          }           

    }




    o/p-
org:(null)
dod:(null)
internet:(null)
snmpV2:(null)
security:(null)
private:(null)
experimental:(null)
mgmt:(null)
directory:(null)
snmpModules:(null)
snmpProxys:(null)
snmpDomains:(null)
snmpMIB:(null)
snmpFrameworkMIB:(null)
.........
........
```

I am getting the null for all the nodes,

Kindly tell me why I am not able to get the description of nodes as it is available .when I am using the command line option as follow

```
snmptranslate -On -Td 1.3.6.1.6.3.10

Result
-----------
 .1.3.6.1.6.3.10
snmpFrameworkMIB MODULE-IDENTITY
  -- FROM       SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB
  DESCRIPTION   "The SNMP Management Architecture MIB

                     Copyright (C) The Internet Society (2002). This
                     version of this MIB module is part of RFC 3411;
                     see the RFC itself for full legal notices.
                    "
::= { iso(1) org(3) dod(6) internet(1) snmpV2(6) snmpModules(3) 10 }
```

`1.3.6.1.6.3.10` is the `oid` of the `snmpFrameworkMIB`  but you can see above the node in my program got null as its `description`.

Can any one know what is the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `net-snmp` `MIB` parser does not turn on DESCRIPTION string storage
in particular because it takes more memory.

To print description call:

```
snmp_set_save_descriptions(1);
```

before calling `init_snmp()` to force saving of the DESCRIPTION clauses.

The function `void            snmp_set_save_descriptions(int);`

declared in `include/net-snmp/mib_api.h` and defined in `snmplib/ucd_compat.c`.

**Definition**:

```
void
snmp_set_save_descriptions(int save)
{
   netsnmp_ds_set_boolean(NETSNMP_DS_LIBRARY_ID, 
                          NETSNMP_DS_LIB_SAVE_MIB_DESCRS, save);
}
```

EDIT:

call `snmp_set_save_descriptions(1);` before `init_snmp()` Also ..`init_snmp()` calls `netsnmp_init_mib()` So not need to call `netsnmp_init_mib()` explicitly if one is calling `init_snmp()`

Comment: Thanks,Grijesh ,for the answer.