# Given an OID, how do I find the corresponding MIB?

Tags: c, net-snmp, mib

I'm using net-snmp.  Given a specific OID such as `.1.3.6.1`, how do I find the corresponding 
`MIB/module/filename/anything` where that OID is described?

I've looked through all the `#include file in <net-snmp/*>` but I cannot figure it out.

I was expecting something along the lines of:

```
struct module *netsnmp_get_module_from_oid( oid *, int oidlen );
```

Comment: Off-course there is do you have source code of net-snmp look you will find in parse.c.

Comment: [**Please read this question and its answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641802/why-the-description-of-the-snmp-oid-giving-null/13776327#13776327)

Comment: Yes, I have the source, and no, that question is about getting the OID description text which isn't saved by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It is a 3-step process:

```
struct tree *head = get_tree_head();
struct tree *t = get_tree( o, l, head );
struct module *m = find_module( t->modid );
```

This gives the module name, the filename, and a list of imports made by the module which can then be looked up further.  When calling this with the `.1.3.6.1` example from the original question, this gives me:

```
NAME=SNMPv2-SMI
FILE=/usr/share/mibs/ietf/SNMPv2-SMI
COUNT=3
#0: LABEL=joint-iso-ccitt, ID=-1
#1: LABEL=ccitt, ID=-1
#2: LABEL=iso, ID=-1
```